# python receiving from a socket

Tags: java, python, android, sockets

So I have a simple socket server on an android emulator. When I'm only sending data to it, it works just fine. But then if I want to echo that data back to the python script, it doesn't work at all. Here's the code that works:

android:

```
try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            while (checkingForClients) {

                try {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    line = null;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.d("ServerActivity", line);

                        /* THIS IS THE LINE THAT DOESN'T WORK*/
                        //out.println(line);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if(incomingData == null){
                                    Log.e("Socket Thingey", "Null Error");
                                }
                                //out.println(line);

                                incomingData.setText("Testing");

                                incomingData.setText(line);


                            }
                        });

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

python:

```
import socket 

host = 'localhost' 
port = 5000
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host,port)) 
s.send('Hello, World!') 
# data = s.recv(size) THIS LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS
s.close() 
print 'Received:' , data
```

So there are 2 commented lines. Without those lines, it works perfectly. But if I add in `s.recv(size)` in python it just freezes and I assume waits for the received data. But the problem is that the android code never gets the sent data. So I have no idea what to do.

Keep in mind I'm new to python and to sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that all of your data actually *does* get sent without having to close the socket, do **not** use the `send` method of your socket -- use its `sendall` method instead!  Look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.sendall#socket.socket.sendall) for `sendall`...:

> Unlike send(), this method continues
>   to send data from string until either
>   all data has been sent or an error
>   occurs.

while those for `send`, just above in the same page, say

> Returns the number of bytes sent.
>   Applications are responsible for
>   checking that all data has been sent;
>   if only some of the data was
>   transmitted, the application needs to
>   attempt delivery of the remaining
>   data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem, you missed socket.shutdown() in your code:

```
s.send('Hello, World!')
s.shutdown(1)
data = s.recv(size)
s.close() 
print 'Received:' , data
```

You Learn Something New...
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

The Android code is reading lines, so you need probably to send a \n or possibly \r\n at the end of your Python send string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error bro, when i wanted to `recv()` data from java to python.
So, I thought that python `connect.send()` worked with no stop to wait the other processess
try to put `s.shutdown(1)` after `s.send()` like this:-

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.1.8", 2307))
sock.listen()
con, adr = sock.accept()
con.sendall(b"download test.txt")
con.shutdown(1)
print(con.recv(4096))
```